# How to simulate join concept using Micro service architecture

Tags: sql, database, microservices

I'm new at micro service architecture,
for instance we have two separate services in isolate machines and two sql databases,
Location.Service has a db like below

```
Locations:
[
{Id: key, Name: string}
]
```

Product.Service has a db like below

```
Products:
[
{Id: key, Name: string, LocationId: key}
]
```

these two services can work beside together properly using event based message protocol like AMQP and everything sound really nice.
but I a have problem with listing products in UI like this

```
ProductId(ok), ProductName(ok), ProductLocationId(ok), ProductLocationName(???)
```

How could I have a solution for listing products with their location Name ?
in simple monolith application, we could easily have join between these tables but problem raises on multiple databases ?
**Solution1:** query should has a nested for having locationName for example like this in ORM tools

```
var products = productService.select(p => new ProductDto{
ProductId= p.Id,
ProductName= p.Name,
LocationId= p.LocationId,
LocationName= locationService.getNameById(p.LocationId)
}).ToList();
```

may be this way is not reasonable
**Solution2:** changing the db design for ProductService like this

```
Products
[
{Id: key, Name: string, LocationId: key, LocationName: string} 
]
```

in this way I should update all products location name(using event message) if the name of location using locationService has been changed
so, I think this way should raise some confusing in project's structure

**Solution3:** these two services should be in the same service!
so in agile projects, we can't estimate future so we had to come to all services to one service that obviously is not recommended!

**What is the best idea for solving this issue ?**

Comment: AS you already mentioned ,you are using event based system , instead of using any of above method or answer give below ,here is my thought , create an event in your product service says "GetLocationByID(List<ID>) , from the API call getProducts and then getallLocation ids from products and call getLocationById event which will be picked up by location service and return back the location then you can simply map them. or better implement same even in both the service and based on event both will repospond back with message required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you came up with Product and location micro services based on some factors. Since you need correlation between these 2 datasets, this has to be done in another micro service which is responsible for this. This new service will interact with these 2 services to get things done

Comment: I'm wondering if you could take an example on this problem?
you mean I ought to create another service for instance named Location.Product.Service that uses solution 1 to correlate these another service?

Comment: @AliKhalili Yes. Name this service as per the functionality. Location.Product.Service is not intuitive. Not sure who down voted mine and 
[Constantin Galbenu] answer below but please give reason even when you down vote to bring the discussion and concrete results.
I have to upvote Constantin Galbenu answer

Answer (score 0):

Every microservice should have *one* responsibility. This keeps them *micro*. So, `Product MS` is responsible for enforcing business rules on products, `Location MS` is responsible for enforcing business rules on locations.

On the other hand you have a third responsibility: to list all/some of the products along with their locations in a human readable way. For this you need another microservice who will have that responsibility. This third microservice should listen to events from both the other microservices and keep an eventually consistent list of products joined with their locations.

BTW: none of the microservices should know/care that the others have a `sql` or `nosql` or whatever database used internally, that's against the microservices architecture.